# Grails PayPal SDK integration

Tags: grails, paypal, dependency-management

I am new to Maven and I have no idea how to integrate maven projects in the BuildConfig file of Grails.

I would like to integrate the Java SDK of PayPal:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK

As you can see there is a pom.xml file included. So there should be a way to integrate this easily in the BuildCOnfig file

I tried the following but this didn't work

```
compile ":com.paypal.sdk:rest-api:1.2.3"
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to defectus' answer I got a bit further. Now I get another error:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
|Downloading: com/paypal/sdk/rest-api-sdk/1.2.3/rest-api-sdk-1.2.3.pom
|Downloading: com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.2/gson-2.2.2.pom
|Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.pom
|Downloading: org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.10/slf4j-parent-1.7.10.pom
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:zip:1.2.3 from/to m2repo_spockframework_org_ext_ (http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/): m2repo.spockframework.org (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be in your `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
...
   dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:1.2.3'
   }
}
```

I guess the leading `:` could be the culprit.

Comment: That's weird - the artefact should be available - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk/rest-api-sdk/1.2.5

Comment: mhh I ended up downloading the jar and putting it in my lib folder. Maybe I need to include some mavenrepo that I am missing?

Comment: It should all be in the main m2 repo.